# Webcomic about a boy visited by a young demon who emerges from under his bed and loves cookies

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I read this within the last 5 years, so somewhere in the 2012-2017 timeframe. I don't remember exactly why I lost track of it... western art style, involves a young boy who has a succubus emerge from under his bed. He winds up getting her to try cookies, and she finds she enjoys them a great deal. As it turns out, she's immature herself, just starting out. I want to say that it's a standard [monster under the bed](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThingsThatGoBumpInTheNight) scenario where her race gets energy from scaring kids.

Anyway, they start falling for each other in an awkward sort of young love way, complicated by that she can't let her superiors know she's revealed who and what she is to a human. I remember there being a capital-letter Council referred to. The other thing I remember about it (which may account for me deciding to stop checking in on it) was that there was occasional female nudity due to the demons not really having any real attachment to clothes.

I think she was blue or purple, had either horns or long ears, and had wings of some sort. They at one point sneak out for cookies from the refrigerator in the middle of the night and he has to hide her from his parents, that sort of sitcom hijinx.

And... found it in the process of doing a search for `webcomic Monster Under The Bed` due to me mentioning as much above.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to that. I just binge-read the entire thing.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean [this guy](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/iannielli-legend/images/6/6e/Cookie_monster.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150918140937)?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: Pretty dang sure. ^_^ Although I'm sure there's an NSFW Cookie Monster story out there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The webcomic is, appropriately enough, *[The Monster Under the Bed](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WebComic/TheMonsterUnderTheBed)*, and [started in 2014](http://themonsterunderthebed.net/?comic=test-post). I'll use the summary from TV Tropes.

> Tim is a perfectly ordinary 18-year-old boy, who has nothing special going for him. At least, that's what you would think if you didn't know about his nightly visits from his girlfriend, who happens to be a dark-skinned demon from another dimension. And the portal she uses to get to Earth just happens to be located right under Tim's bed.

**Fair Warning** The comic is as NSFW as I remembered, with the current front page (not what's linked above) featuring nudity.

Comment: I seem to recall a lot of readers were quite grumpy about the fact that the comic starts NSFW, then becomes SFW for the next 500 panels, with little or no nudity after the first couple of panels